# Arduino Uno blinking YL "Programmer is not responding"

Tags: arduino, led, arduino-uno

*Hey guys so I'm pretty new to Arduino and I've been having some trouble with my Uno MC, I decided to pick one up as a little side project in the January sales and only just freed up the time to really start using it.*

**The first problem is,** when I hook up my Uno to my windows 64x PC using a UsbA-B cable (for power) I get a blinking YL on the Uno.

**Second problem is**, when I attempt to upload an example sketch to the Uno, for instance, "Blink" using the Arduino IDE I get the following error.

> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Have no idea how to fix the issue, but here's some information I know:

- My board does show up in Computer Management under my COM3 port as "Arduino Uno" so I believe my drivers aren't the issue here.
- I also have the correct board selected in the IDE.
- I reinstalled the IDE and reset my computer after installing the drivers, none ofthe errors were fixed.
- I've tried holding down the reset button on the Uno (As shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plCxXwiUK-w) and that doesn't solve my issue.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Tools>Port in the IDE I inexplicably had (COM1) as my active port and *not* port (COM3) where my Uno actually was.

Program now successfully uploads without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Boot Loader.To do this you can use a micro controller Programmer such as `USBasp` and your Arduino software.First insert your `atmega328` micro controller on Programmer then use Burn Bootloader in Tools menu of Arduino software then return back your atmega to its location on Arduino.